# How do I put spaces in between individual characters when creating the triangle using nested for loops?

Tags: java, nested-loops

My apologies if this individual question is a duplicate, but I have not seen any specific answers to this particular problem.

I am trying to put spaces in between each individual character in a triangle I created using nested for loops in the code below.

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 5; j >= 1; j--) {
            if (j > i)
                System.out.print(" ");
            else
                System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= (5 - i + 1); j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This outputs:

```
    1
   21
  321
 4321
54321

12345
 1234
  123
   12
    1
```

However, it is required to be:

```
        1

      2 1

    3 2 1

  4 3 2 1

5 4 3 2 1


1 2 3 4 5

  1 2 3 4

    1 2 3

      1 2

        1
```

I've tried putting `" "` on either as well as both sides of the print statement, as I did with the reverse of these two triangles, to no avail. Am I missing something?

Comment: Wherever you print j, just add a space like so System.out.print(j + " ");

Comment: I end up with the wrong format after adding a space at the end. It is centered when the required output isn't.

Comment: change System.out.print(j) to System.out.print(" " + j), change System.out.print(" ") to System.out.print("  ") (two spaces) and call System.out.println() twice.

Comment: Thank you! I went back through and you were right, I needed two spaces in the System.out.print(" ").

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this.

```
    int spaces=10;
    int z;
    for (int i = 1; i <=5 ; i++) {
        spaces=spaces-2;
        for (int j = 0; j<=spaces ; j++) {
            if(j!=spaces)
                System.out.print(" ");
            else {
                z=i;
                while (z >= 1) {
                    System.out.print(z + " ");
                    z--;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    spaces=-2;
    int m;
    for (int i = 1; i <=5 ; i++) {
        spaces=spaces+2;
        for (int j = 0; j <=spaces ; j++) {
            if(j!=spaces)
                System.out.print(" ");
            else{
                z=i;
                m=1;
                while (m<=6-z) {
                    System.out.print(m + " ");
                    m++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change `System.out.print(j);` to `System.out.print(j + " ");`

Comment: I tried that already and it does not work for these triangles. Is there another method?

Comment: Then try `System.out.print(j + "\t");`